# Problems using layout in R - I want a Precipitation plot on top of a heat map

Tags: r, layout

I'm new to R and I am trying to add a precipitation trend line on top of my heat map and someone suggested I try using layout.

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve

[Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ3Rw.png)

I have created my heat map and my precipitation graph and now I'm trying to use layout to have my precipitation graph on top of my heat map with the x axis not visible and y axis visible.

Here is an example of my plots

[Precipitation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eekyh.png)

[Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VAKd.png)

Here is the code that I have tried to use for layout:

```
layout.matrix <- matrix(c(2, 1, 0, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)

 layout(mat = layout.matrix,
 heights = c(1, 2), # Heights of the two rows
 widths = c(2, 2)) # Widths of the two columns

 layout.show(2)


#Plot 1
 par(mar = c(4, 4, 0, 0))
 TalusNorthHeatMap <- wtr.heat.map(TalusNorthdf, zlim = c(0, 20),
                              xlab = "Date",
                              ylab = "Depth (m)")

#Plot 2
 par(mar = c(0, 0, 4, 4))
 ggplot(data = PrecipTS, mapping = aes (x=Date, y=Precip...mm.))+
 geom_line()+
 labs (x="Date", y="Precipitation (mm)", xaxt = n, yaxt = s)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

`layout` does not work for ggplot and rLakeAnalyzer packages.

You can go with `arrange.grid` from gridExtra package.

Or try this for Base R plot functions:

```
#get some data and transform to matrix:

sp.wtr <- load.ts(wtr.path)
wtrmat <- as.matrix(sp.wtr[,2:ncol(sp.wtr)])
rownames(wtrmat) <- sp.wtr[,1]

# create the plot
layout(matrix(c(2,1,1,1),ncol=1))

par(mar=c(5,4,0,4))
image(as.POSIXct(rownames(wtrmat),format="%s",zone="GMT"),
   rev(as.numeric(substr(colnames(wtrmat)5,nchar(colnames(wtrmat)))))*-1,
   wtrmat[,ncol(wtrmat):1], col = colorRampPalette(c("#ee82ee","#0036ff","#00efff","#00ce07",
   "#ffee00", "#ff0000"))(200), 
   yaxt = "n",xlab="",ylab="Depths (m)",zlim=c(-5,25),ylim=c(-18,0))

axis(2,at=seq(-20,0,5),seq(20,0,-5),las=1)
box()


par(mar=c(0,4,4,4))
plot(as.POSIXct(rownames(wtrmat),format="%s"),rnorm(200,15),
   type="l",xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="Precipitation (mm)",las=1)
```

Comment: when I run the firs line of code I get Error "objects not found'

Comment: @HeatherShaw Odd... The first line doesn't call for an object, the plotting code was copied from your question. Did you miss a letter or something?

Comment: I re-copied your code and looked for any missing letters. Now I get the following error "Error in .External.graphics(C_layout, num.rows, num.cols, mat, as.integer(num.figures),"

Comment: Now, I see that `layout` is ignored by ggplot (I didn't try because you didn't provide a reproducible example). My solution only works with Base R graphichs. You can try with `grid.arrange` from gridExtra package or use Base R functions (e.g. `image` and`plot`) to create the plot.

Comment: See my edits for a base R solution.